# Simplify system of expressions with cases

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have a system of equations that looks something like this:

```
(C[1] == -1 || C[1] == 1) && (C[1] == 1 || x < -1 || x > 1) && (C[2] == -1 || C[2] == 1)
```

I would like to simplify based on all possible values of C[_]

```
case(C[1] == 1) && case(C[1] == -1) && case(C[2] == 1) && case(C[2] == -1)
```

Note that I know C[_] is either 1 or -1

so the result would be the loosest bounds of x

```
x < -1 || x > 1
```

I would like this to work for any number of C[_] values

thanks

Comment: Maybe I'm tired but `case(C[1] == 1)` signifies multiplying an equation by `case` in Mathematics.  Maybe you meant to write `case[C[1] == 1]`, which would pass an equation to a function named `case` (which is not defined above).  But I don't really understand they would be connected with `&&`.

Comment: Maybe this?: `DeleteDuplicates@ Cases[(C[1] == -1 || C[1] == 1) && (C[1] == 1 || x < -1 || x > 1) && (C[2] == -1 || C[2] == 1), _C == _, Infinity]` -- Not exactly the same, but sort of close.

Comment: `expr /. (C[_] == -1 || C[_] == 1) :> True` Your first expression would properly evaluate to `C[1] == 1 || x < -1 || x > 1` rather than just `x < -1 || x > 1`

Comment: Or, `Simplify[(C[1] == -1 || C[1] == 1) && (C[1] == 1 || x < -1 ||  x > 1) && (C[2] == -1 || C[2] == 1), C[_] == 1 || C[_] == 1]` yields `True`, not `x < -1 || x > 1`.